# Annotate many to many with initial model django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have these two models

```
class Word(Model):
    word = CharField()
    categories = ManyToManyField('Category')

class Category(Model):
    name = CharField()
```

What I want to do is to output number of words for each set of categories:

```
General (3 words)
General, IT (7 words)
Medicine (1 word)
Archaic Words, IT (10 words)
```

This means, that, for example, there are 3 words, that have only one category, namely General.

What is the way to accomplish it in the smallest possible number of queries?

First step is to fetch all possible sets, I use PostgreSQL:
all_sets = `Word.objects.annotate(category_names=ArrayAgg('categories__name')).values_list('category_names', flat=True).distinct()`

What next?
I can, of course, fetch the number of words for every set:

```
for category_set in all_sets:
    queryset = Word.objects.annotate(n=Count('categories')).filter(n=len(category_set))
    for cat in category_set:
        queryset = queryset.filter(categories__name=cat)
```

But I will hit the database for the every set of categories.
Can this be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get everything in a single query:

```
categories = Category.objects.annotate(n_words=Count('word_set'))
for category in categories:
    print('{category.name} ({category.n_words})'.format(category))
```